# 502 Bad Gateway for npm publish

Tags: npm, gitlab

I am trying to publish a npm package to gitlab registry and while doing so we are facing 502 bad gateway error. This gitlab registry is not accessible on the internet and can be accessed only inside network. Not sure why this is happening. Any help/solution to this is much appreciated.

Sharing the error message below for reference -

```
npm notice Publishing to https://gitlab.company.net/api/v4/projects/69/packages/npm/
npm ERR! code E502
npm ERR! 502 Bad Gateway - PUT https://gitlab.company.net/api/v4/projects/69/packages/npm/react
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-17T07_15_37_249Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? we are also facing same issues with larger components

Comment: Hi, if you are using Gitlab registry then it won't support publishing of the packages that have package.json with more than 30k characters